# Failed when storing NSMutableArray into plist in swift

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray, plist

I'm writing a swift codes for iphone. In my app I need to store some friends info. Currently I use plist to store the data. I have referred to lots of examples of reading/writing NSMutableArray from/into plist, but when I tried to store an NSMutableArray it just doesn't work.

Below is my codes, finally the result is "nil".

```
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let filename = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent("FriendList.plist")

var FM = NSFileManager()
if FM.createFileAtPath(filename, contents: nil, attributes: nil) {
    if (arrayToBeStored?.writeToFile(filename, atomically: false) != nil) { 
        if NSFileManager().fileExistsAtPath(filename){
            let arrayFromPlist = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: filename)

            //everything goes well except "arrayFromPlist" is just nil.

            println(arrayFromPlist) 
        }else{
            println("Plist was not actually created!")
        }
    }else{
        println("Failed to store the array into plist.")
    }  
}else{
    println("Failed to create file.")
}
```

Anyone has ideas what's wrong in my codes?

Comment: Why is it not working? Please don't add it to the comments. Update your question instead with that information.

Comment: @kkuilla I don't have further information to show as there is no syntax error. I am expecting "println(arrayFromPlist)" to show some data in the plist file while as a result there is nothing output.

Answer (score 0):

"arrayToBeStored.writeToFile" returns a boolean, so it's not comparable with "nil".

```
    let arrayToBeStored = NSArray(object: ["test1", "test2"])
    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
    let filename = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent("FriendList.plist")
    var FM = NSFileManager()
    if FM.createFileAtPath(filename, contents: nil, attributes: nil) {
        if arrayToBeStored.writeToFile(filename, atomically: false) {
            if NSFileManager().fileExistsAtPath(filename){
                let arrayFromPlist = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: filename)
                println(arrayFromPlist!)  // => test1, test2
            }else{
                println("Plist was not actually created!")
            }
        } else {
            println("Failed to store the array into plist.")
        }
    }else{
        println("Failed to create file.")
    }
```

Xcode 6.2 version:

```
let arrayToBeStored = NSArray(object: ["test1", "test2"])
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let filename = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent("FriendList.plist")
var FM = NSFileManager()
if FM.createFileAtPath(filename, contents: nil, attributes: nil) {
    if arrayToBeStored.writeToFile(filename, atomically: false) {
        if NSFileManager().fileExistsAtPath(filename) {
            let arrayFromPlist = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: filename)
            println(arrayFromPlist![0][0])  // => test1
        }else{
            println("Plist was not actually created!")
        }
    } else {
        println("Failed to store the array into plist.")
    }
}else{
    println("Failed to create file.")
}
```

[image]

Comment: I first wrote the code as you said but xcode advised to fix it to this way. If I insist the way as you said the system just shows "Optional type '$T6??' connot be used as a boolean; test for '!=nil' instead"

Comment: I was using Xcode 6.3 + Swift 1.2 and there's a few differences. I've added a verision for Xcode 6.2 and Swift 1.1 in my answer.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see the differences of the codes... can you explain more? moreover, the return value of writeToFile() shall only affects the output of "if" function and saving process shall not be affected, isn't it?

Comment: Did you try running it? The difference was about the forced downcast - but nevermind. // At the end of the `writeToFile` operation, it returns `true` or `false`, see the docs. This code snippet works, I've tested it in a demo app. If it doesn't work for you, please explain why and post some code snippet showing what's different in your version.